# combine two return statements into one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, return

i have the following code:

```
 const Test = obj && obj.length > 0 && obj.map((myguids2, key) => {
    const url2 = myguids2.predicatList.map(mypredicats => {
        const url = mypredicats.p
        var arr = url.split('/')[3]
        return ( 
                            <div>{arr}</div>
                )
    })
    const content = myguids2.guidList.map((myqueriedguids, key) => {
        return (
            <tr>
                 <td>{myqueriedguids.guid.includes('http://linkedbuildingdata.net/ifc/resources20201208_005325/') ? <MyPopUp myproperties={guidList} myguidnames={myqueriedguids.guid}>{myqueriedguids.guid}</MyPopUp> : myqueriedguids.guid}</td>
            </tr>
            )
    })
    return content

})
```

i want to combine the output from url2 with the output coming from content into a two column table with url2 in the left table column and content in the right table

is there way to structure the function in such a way?

Comment: how would you like the output to be?

Comment: from the question it appears the desire is a two column table - so adding another `<td>` to the table row being created would likely solve the challenge Please add additional clarity including the desired output to your question.

Comment: What should happen if `myguids2.predicatList` has a different length than `myguids2.guidList`?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss you got that right, i want to render a two table component where the output of the url2 is seen in the first column and the output of the content gets renderd in the second column. However, currently anything i try renders the output either in a single column or everything in a single row

Comment: @Bergi that  can't be as both myguids2.predicatlist (which contains the title) and myguids2.guidlist contains the content for the title are equal to each other

Answer (score 1):

Just return an object

```
const Test = obj && obj.length > 0 && obj.map((myguids2, key) => {
        const url2 = myguids2.predicatList.map(mypredicats => {
            const url = mypredicats.p
            var arr = url.split('/')[3]
            return ( 
                                <div>{arr}</div>
                    )
        })
        const content = myguids2.guidList.map((myqueriedguids, key) => {
            return (
                <tr>
                     <td>{myqueriedguids.guid.includes('http://linkedbuildingdata.net/ifc/resources20201208_005325/') ? <MyPopUp myproperties={guidList} myguidnames={myqueriedguids.guid}>{myqueriedguids.guid}</MyPopUp> : myqueriedguids.guid}</td>
                </tr>
                )
        })
        return { content, url2  }
    
    })
```

Then you can access properties by

`Test.content` or `Test.url2`

Comment: if i do that it'll return undefined

Answer (score 0):

So the best way for now is to split the Const Test into two variables one containing the url2 and one the content. using a return statement i managed to put  {url2} : {Test}  to gain the two column output